# wordpress Do not show new image attachment in media

Tags: uploads

when I want to upload a image I can't, it shows error something wrong happened please try again later.but the image will be uploaded in host and even i check the database it will be created post with type attachment but the id is 0 and the guid(image link) is empty!

Comment: Can you check your server's error logs? There might be more information about the error.

Comment: i check the error_log but couldnt find the problem yet, the error is : Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in wordpress database INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ...

Comment: @Rup i even deactivated all plugin and change to default theme but still cant upload an image.any idea how to solve it..?